.NET 6 dll reference in .NET Framework 4.5.2
I have a base project on .NET Framework 4.5.2 and I have a .NET 6 class library.
From that class library I created the dll, integrated it in the lib folder of the .NET Framework project added a project reference to the dll and used some Methods of the class lib.
On runtime when it gets to calling one of the methods an Exception is thrown.
The file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or a dependency of it could not be found. The system cannot find the specified file'.

I found out it's teh incompatibility of .NET Framework and .NET Core
So my idea was to make the .NET 6 class lib project a .NET Standard project as it should be compatible with .NET Framework 4.5.2 according to this
But I don't think I'll be able to convert the .NET Framework project into a .NET Standard because in .NET Standard 1.2 there don't seem to be any of the usual functions, such as Path.GetTempPath() or File Read/Write in general.
So can anybody tell me what my opportunities I have here or is .NET Standard my only solution here?
Btw upgrading the .NET Framework project involves a lot more work
